# Best way to do this layout without nesting layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments

From my vague understanding of layout managers I think that nesting layouts inside layouts can be inefficient (is this true for android too?)

I am trying to do this layout but have having to next layouts. Is there a better layout manager I could use so that things are not nested? All of the components are currently fragments so it is a case of laying out the fragments rather than the individual components.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm with Jim, I wouldn't worry too much about a single extra layer of nesting. However, I *believe* this should be possible with a `RelativeLayout`. I put the following layout together, however, I wasn't quite able to get everything to line up. Feel free to use this as a starting point if you want to play around with it: http://pastie.org/9428221

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to get that look without nested layouts. If so, it's because you're doing a lot of graphics that probably isn't necessary (not knowing your other requirements). And by "a lot of graphics" I mean from your image, if you want dynamic content in each box, then you must use nested layouts unless you have one layout and then re-draw the cent portion of the screen to give the effect of nested layouts.

Unless you have a performance problem, you don't need to worry about the efficiency with a low number of layouts (i.e. less than 100 or so). I have several apps with several layers of nested layouts (up to 10 *layers* of nesting) and no measurable difference in performance.

If you have a ScrollView or ListView with hundreds of children, then you might be concerned with nested layouts. I have worked with a few of these, and it can make a difference. For example, I had a ListView with 5,000 or so items, each had about 5 layouts. When I dropped it to 3, I noticed a difference on the backend. Neither were noticeable to the user. (And no, I could not recycle the view containers efficiently since each item essentially needed it's own layout - partial recycling was possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Though it's a bit complex to set up, you can use [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) to achieve that. Assuming the top and bottom views have a fixed height, that would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:background="#ffff070c"
        android:layout_gravity="top"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#ff12ff1a"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#ff0906ff"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#ff737373"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:background="#ffbebebe"></FrameLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

which produces this:

[image]

Comment: Nice! I always forget that GridLayout exists.